# Iterating over strings in python

Tags: python

```
>>> bob = "bob"
>>> range(0, len(bob))
[0, 1, 2]
>>> bob[0:2]
'bo'
>>> bob[0:3]
'bob'
```

Is there a convenient way to iterate over strings in python when I need the index number? If I make a for loop with `range(0, len(astring))`, it will only end up going up to the second-to-last character: I would instead have to write `range(0, len(astring) + 1)`, which is kind of annoying. I can't do `for c in astring` because I am taking substrings. Suggestions?

Comment: Why is it annoying to add one?

Comment: I suppose you could always write a wrapper function to replace `len` such that it returns the result of `len` but with 1 added to it.

Comment: @BrenBarn There's good reason to have separate notations for inclusive and exclusive bounds. For example, `[x, y]` vs `[x, y)` in mathematics, and `x to y` vs `x until y` in the scala core library. It's a more direct expression of your intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i,c in enumerate('bob'):
    print('{}: {}'.format(c,i))

b: 0
o: 1
b: 2
```

Your bit about "substrings" is a bit under-specified, but chances are slicing will do what you need:

```
s = 'banana'

for i,c in enumerate(s):
    print(s[i:])

banana
anana
nana
ana
na
a
```

notably, you can leave off either the start or end bound to a slice (or both!) and the slice will just go all the way up to that end.

Comment: I got the impression the OP wanted to loop over substrings, not characters.

Comment: @DSM well then just replace `'bob'` with bob's substring, no?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have:

```
>>> st='a string with substrings'
```

Of course it is easy to just split that:

```
>>> st.split()
['a', 'string', 'with', 'substrings']
```

But suppose you want to deal with indices of the string based on some condition.

You can define the indices that you want (trivially by spaces here, but could be some other condition):

```
>>> sub_strings=[0]+[i+1 for i, c in enumerate(st) if c.isspace()]+[len(st)]
```

Then you can use `slice` like so:

```
>>> for t in zip(sub_strings, sub_strings[1:]):
...    print st[slice(*t)], t
... 
a  (0, 2)
string  (2, 9)
with  (9, 14)
substrings (14, 24)
```